# Will Facebook re-scrape the permalink URL even if og:url is set to the redirect target to avoid an error in Debugger?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

For my Open Graph objects I made permalinks like

(1) `http://www.example.com/go?id=123456`

that redirect to a non-permanent URL like

(2) `http://www.example.com/controller/something.php?session=abc&page=654321`

When I set `og:url` to (1), the [Debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) shows a "Circular redirect path" error, independent of whether I use a 301, 302, 303 or 307 redirect.

When I publish an Open Graph story that refers to an object with (1) as URL, on Facebook the link to the object is (2).

When (2) changes, will Facebook get that change after 7 days by re-scraping (1)? I'm unsure because I cannot see (1) anywhere on Facebook's GUI.